# Eclipse error when I install egit on juno

Tags: github, eclipse-plugin, egit

I received a error when I egit on Juno version of Eclipse.

I didn't install anything in Eclipse. I just did what egit installation said.

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: EGit Mylyn 2.2.0.201212191850-r (org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.feature.group 2.2.0.201212191850-r)
  Software being installed: EGit Project Set Support 2.1.0.201209190230-r (org.eclipse.egit.psf.feature.group 2.1.0.201209190230-r)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Git Team Provider Core 2.2.0.201212191850-r (org.eclipse.egit.core 2.2.0.201212191850-r)
    Git Team Provider Core 2.1.0.201209190230-r (org.eclipse.egit.core 2.1.0.201209190230-r)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: EGit Mylyn 2.2.0.201212191850-r (org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.feature.group 2.2.0.201212191850-r)
    To: org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.ui [2.2.0.201212191850-r]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: EGit Mylyn UI 2.2.0.201212191850-r (org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.ui 2.2.0.201212191850-r)
    To: package org.eclipse.egit.core [2.2.0,2.3.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: EGit Project Set Support 2.1.0.201209190230-r (org.eclipse.egit.psf.feature.group 2.1.0.201209190230-r)
    To: org.eclipse.egit.core [2.1.0,2.2.0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and figured out if you don't install the "EGit Project Set Support", it will work. Because that's the only one that still uses 2.1.0. The rest is already on 2.2.0. So I guess the "EGit Project Set Support" will be updated later to 2.2.0.

Comment: "EGit Project Set Support" is no longer needed as a separate feature with newer Eclipse versions, it is provided by the core EGit feature.

Comment: without installing EGit Project Set Support, I installed. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The version of Egit Mylin that you are trying to install depends on version 2.1.0 of EGit, but you already have EGit 2.2.0 installed.

If you just have a couple of plugins to install, I'd recommend starting with a fresh download of eclipse (since Juno SR2 was just released last week).

Try always using the Juno repositories (not the subproject repos) to avoid having such problems. Juno SR 2 was delayed one week because EGit had to withdraw a release, and if you installed that one from the EGit repo before Juno SR 2 was released, you will get errors as the one above.